# How to decompile an Apk to android studio project

Tags: android-studio, apk, decompiling

I want to decompile an apk to its correct form of source code where we can edit that code and can open in android studio as a project

I tried using Apk tool and other but not useful

Answer (score 2):

Fully decompiling an Android APK so that you can modify it and then recompile is next to impossible. This is only realistic for very small Android apps that don't use complex code and libraries.

[Jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx/) can decompile APK files to a gradle project which you can open in Android Studio but common apps are so large and complex that always a number of methods can not be decompiled or the decompiled code is not exactly matching the DEX byte code. So it can be used to decompile a project you have lost the source code of to recover code certain important parts and then copy these part into a new Android Studio project.

If you want to modify the code of an existing APK file the only working way is o use [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/). Note that apktool decompiles the app to smali code which is something like Android dex assembler code. It is pretty hard to read and modifying it requires a lot of knowledge on smali code and how Java/DEX work internally. But using apktool for decompiling and recompiling grants the highest chance that your recompiled app really works in the end.